# Model Integration

Tags: data-mining

I have two models one of them made by using a large dataset, the other one made by using a small dataset. I want to integrate these two datasets. The large dataset has more samples of rare instances. How can I integrate these two models based on the number of instances?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is not specific, this answer is also not specific. I am considering the case where two dataset exists: both have drastically different sizes, and one has more rare cases. It sounds like OP would like to combine the two models into a single general model.

The simplest approach is just to combine the two datasets together and create a new model. Presumably, OP is hesitant to do this due to the "rare instances" that one of the datasets have. This class imbalance can be overcome with [resampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling_and_undersampling_in_data_analysis) (e.g. over-sampling the rare instances). Depending on the type of data, synthesized data can also be used.

A more involved alternative would be to apply [transfer learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning) to the models. Essentially, it just means using a pre-existing model and re-applying it to a different problem. It depends highly on the problem, but there are literature out there that discuss merging models. Unfortunately, without more details on the problem, this is as specific as I can get without rambling on about potentially unrelevant topics.

Comment: These two datasets coming from different resources. Although the concept is similar I don't have enough confidence to make one model. My goal is finding the regression value (especially for rare instances) in the small dataset but I am trying to increase the accuracy of prediction by using a big dataset from other resources. Transfer learning seems to be a good solution but I could not find good resources to use transfer learning in data mining. How Transfer Learning can be used to merge these two models? Is it only use to adopt features.Any suggestions or resources would be appreciated.Thanks